# How to put all words and phrases in list into a search expression (Python)

Tags: python, regex, list, compression, list-comprehension

I have this list of lists:

```
groups = [['|FOOD|','shrimps','chicken wok','bowl of rice'],['|DRINK|','water','cranberry juice','tea']]
```

I'm trying to get the output to be:

```
[['|FOOD|',
  '[lemma="shrimps"]',
  '[lemma="chicken"][lemma="wok"]',
  '[lemma="bowl"][lemma="of"][lemma="rice"]'],
 ['|DRINK|',
  '[lemma="water"]',
  '[lemma="cranberry"][lemma="juice"]',
  '[lemma="tea"]']]
```

So, basically I need every word lemmatized for a corpus search. Some words though, are not words but **phrases**. I've only yet figured out the code for **single words**, here it is:

```
import re
groups = [[f'[lemma="{word}"]' if not ' ' in word and not re.search(r'\|.*\|', word) else word for word in group] for group in groups]
```

This returns **groups** as:

```
[['|FOOD|', 
  '[lemma="shrimps"]', 
  'chicken wok', 
  'bowl of rice'],
 ['|DRINK|', 
  '[lemma="water"]', 
  'cranberry juice', 
  '[lemma="tea"]']]
```

So I made it not include that words containing a whitespace (**phrases**), plus the topic words. What then is the code to deal with these phrases and have them look like like I typed above?

I'm a beginner, so if you know a better way to organise all this data, let me know.

Comment: `[['|FOOD|',
  '[lemma="shrimps"]',
  '[lemma="chicken"][lemma="wok"]',
  '[lemma="bowl"][lemma="of"][lemma="rice"]',
 ['|DRINK|',
  '[lemma="water"]',
  '[lemma="cranberry"][lemma="juice"]',
  '[lemma="tea"]']]` does not look syntactically correct.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You do not really need a regex here, you may use `if not word.startswith("|") and not word.endswith("|")` to check if the entry has no pipes on both ends:

```
groups = [[''.join([r"""[lemma="{}"]""".format(w) for w in word.split()]) if not word.startswith("|") and not word.endswith("|") else word for word in group] for group in groups]
```

See the [Python demo online](https://ideone.com/zXakqK). Output:

```
[['|FOOD|', 
 '[lemma="shrimps"]', 
 '[lemma="chicken"][lemma="wok"]', 
 '[lemma="bowl"][lemma="of"][lemma="rice"]'], 
['|DRINK|', 
 '[lemma="water"]', 
 '[lemma="cranberry"][lemma="juice"]', 
 '[lemma="tea"]']
 ]
```